# Typescript and angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Grocery } from '../../auth/grocery.model';

export interface CartItem {
grocery: Grocery;
  count: number;
 amount: number;
 }

 export class Cart {
count: number = 0;
amount: number = 0;
  items: CartItem[] = [];
  }


  @Injectable()
  export class CartService {
  cart: Cart = new Cart(); 
  constructor(){}
  /* constructor(private Cart: Cart) {
  this.cart = Cart;
  }*/

  addGrocery(grocery: Grocery) {
  console.log(this.cart);
  console.log("gro" + grocery);
  console.log(grocery.sno);
  let item: CartItem = this.findItem(grocery.sno);
  console.log("first" + item);
  if (item) {
  item.count++;
  item.amount += grocery.cost;
  console.log("item" + item.amount);
  } else {
  item = {
    grocery: grocery,
    count: 1,
    amount: grocery.cost
  };
  console.log("else" + this.cart.items.push(item));
  this.cart.items.push(item);
  }
  this.cart.count++;
  this.cart.amount += grocery.cost;
  console.log("cart" + this.cart.amount);
  console.log(item);
  console.log(this.cart);
  return item;
  }

  removeProduct(grocery: Grocery) {
  let item: CartItem = this.findItem(grocery.sno);
  if (item) {
  item.count--;
  item.amount -= grocery.cost;
  if (!item.count) {
    this.remove(item);
  }
  this.cart.count--;
  this.cart.amount -= grocery.cost;
}

return item;
}

removeItem(item: CartItem) {
this.remove(item);
this.cart.count -= item.count;
this.cart.amount -= item.amount;
}

findItem(id: string): CartItem {
for (let i = 0; i < this.cart.items.length; i++) {
  if (this.cart.items[i].grocery.sno === id) {
    return this.cart.items[i];
  }
}
return null;
}

clearCart() {
this.cart.items = [];
this.cart.amount = 0;
this.cart.count = 0;
}

remove(item: CartItem) {
let indx: number = this.cart.items.indexOf(item);
if (indx !== -1) {
  this.cart.items.splice(indx, 1);
}
}
}
```

when calling the cart variable from another component the cart is showing empty and the values are not incremented.

```
addGrocery(grocery: Grocery) {
console.log(this.cart);
console.log("gro" + grocery);
console.log(grocery.sno);
let item: CartItem = this.findItem(grocery.sno);
console.log("first" + item);
if (item) {
  item.count++;
  item.amount += grocery.cost;
  console.log("item" + item.amount);
} else {
  item = {
    grocery: grocery,
    count: 1,
    amount: grocery.cost
  };
  console.log("else" + this.cart.items.push(item));
  this.cart.items.push(item);
}
this.cart.count++;
this.cart.amount += grocery.cost;
console.log("cart" + this.cart.amount);
console.log(item);
console.log(this.cart);
return item;
}
```

In the above code the increment is being done
but in the below code it's showing initial values when calling cart from another component

```
@Injectable()
export class CartService {
cart: Cart = new Cart(); 
constructor(){}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow, Maybe you could tke a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At the moment it is hard to tell what is the question here. And the title does not describe the problem at all.

Comment: Question are quite unclear but assuming your asking why the cart values are empty on a different component. I Would say its because you are initiating a new cart on the different component.

Comment: Can you show us the module that has the CartService as a provider? You need to instantiate CartService in the constructor of the component you are using it in but you have to make sure you don't just add the CartService as a provider everywhere if you want a singleton service.

Comment: when you manipulate any variable from within the service everything is synchronous but my guess is your component code runs before the cart service logic is ran,
if you're not really sure you could just add console.log() calls from within the service and the component and you'll probably see the component calls being called first, 
take a look at observables and promises, you want the component methods to wait for the objects to be passed from the service to the components.